# Apple pie box model and animation

Tags: rigging, bones

What is the best way to animate apple pie box folding from die form to folded view?

I need rather technic then solution. In my case I should be able to fold abstract apple pie box from die form, not vice versa.

These type of box seems to be pretty easy, but on close view no so... I spent whole day and still have no idea how to start folding...

Does blender has any tools to fold and bend faces keeping it's UV geometry constant?

[image: Apple pie box example]

UPD: moonboots thank you for the answer, but...
I think it's a bit dirty and tricky way... I would like (if it's possible) to make it more realistic way...
First of all, applie pie box is not trivial geometry. It's a cross section of bunch of cilinders, you can see them on the gif:

[image]

Actually I created that cross section, and applied bones. Going try to unfold it (at least):

[image]

For now I have problem to pose bone in parralel to XY-plane (the goal is to unfold box). I think I tested all kinds of snapping, but has no luck (
I would be very grateful if someone would explain to me how to rotate a bone parallel to the XY plane?

[image]

UPD2: here is my version, pure bones, as much real as possible, but not strict real... It can be used for cartoon-like animation, but not for packaging production visualization and preview...

Finaly it seems there are should be more dedicated software for package modeling. Paper and folding cardboard physics should be considered much more precisely...

[image]
note that box flaps has arc form when box is folded:
[image]

Comment: it would mean from totally flat position (the one we see on the picture) to its 3D form?

Comment: Yes, from totally flat

Comment: @moonboots, please have a look to my edits to question, thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, I've edited, B-Bones seem to work fine, except I wasn't able to make Subsurf work properly but it's not necessary if your object is subdivided enough.

Comment: nice, but where was your difficulty exactly? why couldn't you "rotate a bone parallel to the XY plane"?

Comment: @moonboots! again, thank you very much for your attention to my question! I updated post, added my version... Finaly for may case (preview for packaging production workflow) blender is unusable for these type of boxes (( too complicated, too much deviation to real world...((

Comment: I don't think you can't achieve a good result, and it was not clear what was your difficulty. I tried about the same solution as yours, with bendy bones, it needs a little bit more precision work but at the end I'm sure it works pretty well...

Comment: Your tried, but devil is on the flaps... Three days ago I also thought its easy...haha...  Look carefully to my gifs... Bones on the flap parented (each one) to bones on the arc, also they had direction to one point (cylinder center axis) and roll to to another point (another cylinder center). Plus a lot of of vertex groups... A lot to do, yes. But not strict result ( I can't align bones strictly to cylinder center (only by hand), thus result is not quite accurate...

Comment: sure, I'm not saying it's easy, but that's the way to go, plus I'm not sure anyone would notice very small flaws. Also I'm wondering if you really need so many bones...

Comment: If we want to transform (with no deform) we need as much bones as possible... Because flaps are cylinder section unfolding to flat and moving same time...

Answer (score 1):

So 2 solutions:

I've tried with ***B-Bones***, it works fine. Don't forget to put the *Subdivision Surface* under the *Armature* modifier, otherwise you'll have bad shading:

[image]

You could also use both ***bones + shapekeys***:

- Create your flat object. Give it 3 bones, one main, one for each face hinge:

[image]

- Give your object a basis shapekey and a second shapekey, modify the object:

[image]

- Mix both shapekeys and bones animations, use the bones to move and close the object:

[image]

Comment: please have a look to my edits to question, thanks in advance!